# How to use F#-defined types within a C# project

Tags: c#, f#

I've implemented F# For Fun And Profit's [Designing for Correctness example](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-for-correctness/) in an F# DLL, which starts like this:

```
module Foo =
    type Item = { Price : double; Name : string }

    type EmptyState = NoItems
    type ActiveState = { UnpaidItems : Item list }
    type CompletedState = { PaidItems : Item list; PurchaseDate : System.DateTime }

    type Cart =
        | EmptyCart of EmptyState
        | ActiveCart of ActiveState
        | CompletedCart of CompletedState

    ....

    let addItemToCart cart item =
        match cart with
        | EmptyCart state -> state.Add item
        | ActiveCart state -> state.Add item
        | CompletedCart state ->
            printfn "ERROR: The cart is paid for"
            cart
    ...

    type Cart with
        static member NewCart = Cart.EmptyCart NoItems
        member this.Add = addItemToCart this
        ....
```

I'm now attempting to create a simple C# console app to use it. My expectation is that I can do something like:

```
var myCart = Foo.Cart.NewCart(); // implicitly creates an EmptyCart

var item = new Foo.Item(123.45, "something");
myCart.Add(item); // adds a new item, changing to ActiveCart
// do other stuff, like adding more items, deleting them, then completing the cart
```

However, `Add` isn't a method:

[image]

Intellisense tells me that `Add` is `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<Foo.Item,Foo.Cart> Cart.Add`.

I'm not sure if I've done something wrong, am missing an annotation, or if I'm misunderstanding the interoperability of C# and F#. Is there, in fact, a way to use this F# code seamlessly in C#?

Comment: Which members do IntelliSense tell you that `FSharpFunc` *does* have?

Comment: `member this.Add x = addItemToCart this x`

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Not sure I understand the question, but `myCart` has `Add`, `Display`, `IsActiveCart`, `IsCompletedCart`, `IsEmptyCart`, `Remove` and `Tag` properties. Member functions appear to only be those intrinsic to objects (`ToString`, `Equals`, etc).

Comment: @PetSerAl: I do already have an EmptyState-specific `Add` function, 
```let addToEmptyState item = ActiveCart {UnpaidItems = [item]}
...
type EmptyState with
 member this.Add = addToEmptyState```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your member `Add` is a property, hence from C# you're going to see something which returns `FSharpFunc` which won't be much help to you.  What you need to do is make `Add` a method by making it take an argument.

```
type Cart with
    static member NewCart = Cart.EmptyCart NoItems
    member this.Add item = addItemToCart this item
```

That's only the first part of the answer, you also need to deal with the question of mutability/immutability.

Because you are using immutable data, your `addItemToCart` function needs to look something like this:

```
let addItemToCart cart item =
    match cart with
    | EmptyCart state -> ActiveCart {UnpaidItems = [item]}
    | ActiveCart state -> ActiveCart {UnpaidItems = item :: state.UnpaidItems}
    | CompletedCart state ->
        printfn "ERROR: The cart is paid for"
        cart
```

(I've simplified this a bit from the example on the page you provided so you can easily see what's actually going on.)

Now, the function `addItemToCart`, when given an empty cart, returns an active cart with one item and when given an active cart with n items, it returns an active carts with n+1 items such that the extra item is prepended to the list.  Note that `addItemToCart` doesn't actually update the state of existing cart, every time you give it a cart as an argument, it gives you a new cart back.

You would then need to use your `Cart` immutably from C# too.

```
var myCart = Foo.Cart.NewCart(); // creates an EmptyCart
var item = new Foo.Item(123.45, "something");
var myUpdatedCart = myCart.Add(item); // adds a new item, returning a new ActiveCart
```

Comment: I think the first problem was an assumption that `member this.Add = addItemToCart this` curried (proper use of the term?) the `addItemToCart state item`. The second, after I addressed this, was that the C# code `myCart.Add(item)` resulted in an empty `myCart`. Not sure why I assumed `myCart` would mutate, but changing my code to `myCart = myCart.Add(item)` correctly gives the behavior I was hoping for.